# Xamarin - Adding to Dark/Light themes

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my App.xaml I have the following (just an example):

```
    <Style Class="Banner" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#00ff00" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#0000ff" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
    </Style>
```

This works fine with:

```
<Label StyleClass="Banner" Text="Hello" />
```

But, if I use one of the Dark/Light themes, the "Banner" StyleClass is ignored.  I was hoping that the StyleClass's I created would add to those of the theme.

I want to be able to 'enhance' the themes, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manged to get this working.  In my App.xaml I have...

```
<!-- Enhancements to the Dark theme -->
<ResourceDictionary x:Name="EnhancedDark">
    <Style Class="Banner" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#000000" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#ffffff" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Large" />
    </Style>
    ...
</ResourceDictionary>

<!-- Enhancements to the Light theme -->
<ResourceDictionary x:Name="EnhancedLight">
    <Style Class="Banner" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#ffffff" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#000000" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Large" />
    </Style>
    ...
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then in my app.cs to set the Dark theme with enhancements I have

```
   Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new DarkThemeResources());
   Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(EnhancedDark); // Important 
   Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(EnhancedLight); // Important
```

And similarly for Light.  Now in my code I can:

```
<Label StyleClass="Banner" ... />
```